# How to know IP address of client machine in angular + .Net core controller setup?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, ip-address

I am developing Angular app and using Asp .Net Core at backend. I want to know IP of client machine on which browser is running at Controller layer. So when a request goes from browser to backend, it is routed through proxy file like below.

```
{
  "/shell/api": {
    "target": "http://<server-name>:1000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/shell": ""
    },
  }
}
```

From angular service, I call server like this.

```
loadData() {
    return this._http.get('shell/api/get/data')
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

At Controller, I expect IP address in below object.

HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress

Now, browser sends request, angular receives it, sends through proxy to Controller. Because of proxy, I get server IP address in Controller.

Is there a way to still get client IP in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the client IP for each request that you are making to server.

If you want to get the client IP in UI, you can use the below code.

```
const findIP = new Promise(r => {
      const w = window;
      const a = new (w['RTCPeerConnection'] || w['mozRTCPeerConnection'] || w['webkitRTCPeerConnection'])({ iceServers: [] });
      const b = () => { };
      a.createDataChannel('');
      a.createOffer(c => a.setLocalDescription(c, b, b), b);
      a.onicecandidate = c => {
        try {
          console.log(c);
          if (c.candidate) {
            c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      };
    }
    );
    findIP.then(ip => {
      this.ip = ip;
    }).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found this work-around in another post too and have done this. I want to avoid this through some configurations if possible. Any way for this?